# Refresh particular section in Lightning

Tags: lightning

[image][image]My requirement is like this : for example: We have 2 rows.Each row contains delete buttons.If I delete one row,other row has to appear in that section. How to achieve it?..
Here delete functionality work after entire page refresh..I need like this if I delete particular row ,other row has to appear in page [not after refresh].

****Particular page block section has to re render? [In image I indicated that section in red Boarder]****

**component side:**

```
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Space_Selected__c[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="SpaceLine" type="Space_Selected__c[]"/>

<div class="slds-grid">
    <div class="slds-col">
        <div class="slds-box slds-box--small slds-theme--shade slds-text-align--bottom">
            <center><h3 class="slds-section-title--divider"></h3> </center>
            <center> 
                <ui:button label="Delete All" press="{!c.DeleteAll}"/>
                <ui:button label="Cancel" press="{!c.CancelAll}"/>
            </center>
             <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
                <tr>
                    <th class="head">Name</th>
                    <th class="head">No of Units</th>
                    <th class="head">Price/Desk</th> 
                    <th class="head">Proposed Price</th>
                    <th class="head">Zopa Limit  </th>
                    <th class="head">Action </th>
                </tr>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.SpaceLine}" var="item" indexVar="indx">>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <ui:outputText value="{!item.Name}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td> 
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <ui:outputText value="{!item.No_of_Desks__c}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td> 
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <ui:outputText value="{!item.Price_Unit__c}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td> 
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <ui:outputText value="{!(item.Price_Unit__c*item.No_of_Desks__c)}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td>
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <ui:outputText value="{!item.ZOPA_Limit__c}"/>
                            </p>   
                        </td>
                        <td class="cell" >
                            <p> 
                                <button type="button" onclick="{!c.DeleteRecord}" id="{!item.Id}" > Delete </button>
                            </p>   
                        </td>  

                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
             </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript side:**

```
DeleteRecord:function(component,event,helper){
             alert('delete Record values');
              var idx=event.target.id;
             alert(idx);
             var DelAction=component.get("c.deleteIndividual");
                  DelAction.setParams({
                      "delId":idx,
                    });
         DelAction.setCallback(this,function(del){
            var state=del.getState();
             alert('state value delete @@'+state);
              if(state=='SUCCESS'){
                var Space=component.get("v.SpaceLine");
                 alert('space values******'+Space);
                 var items=[];
                 for(var i=0;i<Space.length;i++){
                     alert('d value @@@'+del.getReturnValue());
                     if( Space[i]!=del.getReturnValue()){
                         items.push(Space[i]);
                     }
                 }
                  component.set("v.SpaceLine",items);
              }
          });
    $A.enqueueAction(DelAction);
    }
```

**server side:**

```
 @AuraEnabled
public static List<Space_Selected__c> deleteIndividual(string delId){
    system.debug('@@@ delId value@@@'+delId);
    List<Space_Selected__c> deleteSpace=new List<Space_Selected__c>();
    deleteSpace=[select Id,Name,Conference_Credits__c,Proposal__c,No_of_Desks__c,Cost__c,Price_Unit__c from Space_Selected__c where id=:delId];
    system.debug('delete space values@@@'+deleteSpace);
    delete deleteSpace;
    return deleteSpace;
}
```

Comment: Could you please post the screenshot with explanation? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are you getting the to-be-deleted id in DeleteRecord function correctly?

Comment: When I click on delete button,its performing mass delete and showing only one row with null value..but actually i wanted to delete single row..

Comment: Now I Just Edited the code please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the component to ReRender you will need to query back the data to find latest result set .

Your delete apex once run return the no of Rows currently in the Table like below .This is simplest way to handle via server call itself

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Space_Selected__c> deleteIndividual(string delId){
  system.debug('@@@ delId value@@@'+delId);
  List<Space_Selected__c> deleteSpace=new List<Space_Selected__c>();
  deleteSpace=[select Id,Name,Conference_Credits__c,Proposal__c,No_of_Desks__c,Cost__c,Price_Unit__c from Space_Selected__c where id=:delId];
  system.debug('delete space values@@@'+deleteSpace);
  delete deleteSpace;
   List<Space_Selected__c> lstselected = [Select Id,Name,Conference_Credits__c,Proposal__c,No_of_Desks__c,Cost__c,Price_Unit__c from Space_Selected__c];
  return lstselected;
}
```